# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields - Cleaner Way To Code This

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have added advanced custom fields to woocommerce category pages to help with SEO.

Is there a cleaner way to code this as a lot of excess probably don't need

```
        <div class="full top-cat-seo">
                <?php
                $queriedObject=get_queried_object();
                echo get_field('product_category_top_section_seo','product_cat_'.$queriedObject->term_id);
            
                $link1 = get_field('link_url_1','product_cat_'.$queriedObject->term_id);
                $link1name = get_field('link_url_1_name','product_cat_'.$queriedObject->term_id);
                $link2 = get_field('link_url_2','product_cat_'.$queriedObject->term_id);
                $link2name = get_field('link_url_2_name','product_cat_'.$queriedObject->term_id);
                $link3 = get_field('link_url_3','product_cat_'.$queriedObject->term_id);
                $link3name = get_field('link_url_3_name','product_cat_'.$queriedObject->term_id);
                $link4 = get_field('link_url_4','product_cat_'.$queriedObject->term_id);
                $link4name = get_field('link_url_4_name','product_cat_'.$queriedObject->term_id);
            
                if( $link1 ): ?>
                    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link1 ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link1name );?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( $link2 ): ?>
                    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link2 ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link2name );?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( $link3 ): ?>
                    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link3 ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link3name );?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( $link4 ): ?>
                    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link4 ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link4name );?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            
        </div>
```

there are 8 custom fields to create 4 buttons as per here

https://onepoundcrisps.com/cat/brand/kp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a separate conditional statement for each link, you can use a loop to iterate over all the links and display them. Here's how it can be done:

```
<div class="full top-cat-seo">
  <?php
  $queriedObject = get_queried_object();
  echo get_field('product_category_top_section_seo', 'product_cat_' . $queriedObject->term_id);
  ?>
  <?php
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $link = get_field("link_url_{$i}", "product_cat_{$queriedObject->term_id}");
    $linkname = get_field("link_url_{$i}_name", "product_cat_{$queriedObject->term_id}");
    if ($link) {
      ?>
      <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url($link); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($linkname); ?></a>
      <?php
    }
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

Instead of using the `get_field()` function repeatedly, you can use the `get_fields()` function to retrieve all the fields for a specific product category in a single call, and then access the individual fields as an array. Here's how it can be done:

```
<div class="full top-cat-seo">
  <?php
  $queriedObject = get_queried_object();
  $fields = get_fields("product_cat_{$queriedObject->term_id}");
  echo $fields['product_category_top_section_seo'];
  ?>
  <?php
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $link = $fields["link_url_{$i}"];
    $linkname = $fields["link_url_{$i}_name"];
    if ($link) {
      ?>
      <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url($link); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($linkname); ?></a>
      <?php
    }
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop, you build the name of the field from the loop key.  So instead of hardcoding `link_url_1`, you can use `'link_url_' . $i` where `$i` is the loop index.

You can also fetch the link and only fetch the linkname if there is a value.

This means you do 1 set of code and any changes will be reflected on all elements...

```
$queriedObject = get_queried_object();
echo get_field('product_category_top_section_seo', 'product_cat_' . $queriedObject->term_id);

for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $link = get_field('link_url_' . $i, 'product_cat_' . $queriedObject->term_id);

    if ($link) {
        $linkName = get_field('link_url_' . $i . '_name', 'product_cat_' . $queriedObject->term_id);
        echo '<a class="button" href="' . esc_url($link) . '">' . esc_html($linkName) . '</a>';
    }
}
```

I've converted the HTML to an `echo`, if you feel more comfortable with your current version, you should just need to change the field names (just remove the number).